# How te enable changes

Tags: excel

I have written an excel application that reads and write to 3 different workbooks.
Although these workbooks are set to read only, there was no problem. Because when i opened these i got a message box asking to open it read only.
I just had to click no

Now these workbooks are moved to sharepoint and there my troubles began.

The question to open it read only is not in a message box, but on the workbook itself.
And when navigating to it the button doesn't react.

So is stays in read only mode

Comment: Are you using macros to perform actions in your Excel doc?

Comment: No i use VBA code, But the workbook with the VBA code is not located inside sharepoint. Because i know that won't work.